# pyspark writeStream failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: apache-spark

I have download winutils and hadoop.dll (for hadoop 3.2 ) and set HADOOP_HOME properly and added the same to path variable as well. However, I am getting below error when I do, writeStream. Env is windows:

I tried even copying the hadoop.dll to C:\Windows\System32 and it did not help. I verified the versions of winutils and hadoop.dll couple of times and they look OK.

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load() \
  .selectExpr("cast(body as string) as value")

df.writeStream.format("json").option("checkpointLocation","C:\work\checkpoint").option("path", "C:\work\output").start()
```

I strongly feel some issue with local setting and could not figure it out.

The df.writeStream fails with below error:

```
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = cb6bb780-7371-436d-af12-0c92048f06c8, runId = ae1faffc-d6ec-4513-b457-f9aa61f0ef9d]"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
```

Comment: is your spark compiled with Hadoop 3.2?

Comment: Hi, yes. its with Hadoop 3.2. Below is the package that I am using:
spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2

C:\Ravi\work\spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\jars>dir hadoop-*
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is 5C6B-D00B

 Directory of C:\Ravi\work\spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\jars
05/24/2021  10:15 AM            60,244 hadoop-annotations-3.2.0.jar
05/24/2021  10:15 AM           139,058 hadoop-auth-3.2.0.jar
05/24/2021  10:15 AM            44,149 hadoop-client-3.2.0.jar
.. few listed here.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved when I rolled back to older version of spark-hadoop package. Seems, some issue with Hadoop 3.x package that I have. I tried with spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7 package and its working OK. Also, I cleaned up and recreated all the env variables at user level and earlier it was at system level. Now, I dont see the above error.